# query with NOT IN in subquery return exception in c# windows forms with access db

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am using following query in C# code with ms access database, and getting an error of type mismatch in expression;
I have been gone through the searches but as far as suggested my query is correct. when I put values instead of subquery it works fine.

```
select name, qty, type from products
where productid not in (select id from sold where id is not null)
```

I have also tried this with != but did not yeild success. I need to select only those products which are not sold yet.

Exception:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Note: if there is zero record in sold table, still it works fine

Comment: What is the data type of `productid`? Of `id`?

Comment: @mjwills thank you. both have different data types. now working by make same data type

Comment: Can you show the database model and the field types?